# Get click event on a menuitem with subitems (C#)

Tags: c#, events, click, menuitem

I am creating a contextmenu that should contain a listing of all folders, subfolders, and files in a chosen folder. I want the menu to open the files and folders when they are clicked, but the click event doesn't register if the menuitem has subitems.

```
void Foo(string Title)
{
    MenuItem = new MenuItem(Title);
    MenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(MenuItem_Click);
    ContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(MenuItem);
}

void MenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This box will only show when menuitems without subitems are clicked");
}
```

How can I make the click event fire even if the menuitem has subitems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like a menu may not be the most appropriate UI widget here. I believe the reason you don't get a click event raised is that menu items with submenus are assumed to *only* expand their children when clicked, rather than executing any other action.

That's likely to be the assumption of the user, too.

This behaviour is mentioned in the documentation for [`MenuItem.Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.click.aspx):

> Note: If the MenuItems property for the
>   MenuItem contains any items, this
>   event is not raised. This event is not
>   raised for parent menu items.

Comment: It is supposed to be a tiny application that gives access to most used folders, files, websites, etc very easily. My idea is a tray icon with a right click menu, as I cannot see any other controls that would be both easily accessed and hidden when not in use. 

There is no way to make the event raise, then?

Comment: Not without a grotty hack, I suspect. You could add a "leaf" menu item under each directory with the name "[This directory]" though. How would you detect the difference between a user clicking to navigate and them clicking to say "Open this directory"?

Comment: Yes, the "leaf" menu item is the current implementation, but I don't like it much. The user shouldn't need to click to navigate; the popup menus are automatic (double clicking could be an option to minimize confusion -- if the double click event was supported).

Comment: Pop up menus may be automatic in some cases, but many people like to click anyway - I know I do, as it reduces confusion from accidental hovering. It's a confirmatory step, and I certainly wouldn't want it to take an action.

Answer (score 1):

If you launched your popup from a toolstrip, you can subclass the toolstrip and add this code.

```
  override protected void OnItemClicked(ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.Items.Count == 0)
      base.OnItemClicked(e);

    // else do nothing
  }
```

However, the ContextMenu class does not have OnItemClicked, but it has onPopup. I have not tried it but you could try subclassing the ContextMenu

```
public class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
  override protected void OnPopUp(EventArgs e)
  {
        if (this.MenuItems.Count == 0)
          base.OnPopUp(e);

        // else do nothing
  }
}
```

if that does not work then, you could override the two show methods

```
public class MyContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
  override protected void Show (Control c, Point p)
  {
        if (this.MenuItems.Count == 0)
          base.Show (c, p) ;

        // else do nothing
  }

  override protected void (Control c, Point p, LeftRightAlignment z) 
  {
        if (this.MenuItems.Count == 0)
          base.Show (c, p, z) ;

        // else do nothing
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the logic will work, but is an illustration to subclass ContextMenu and intercept the click with your own logic with

if (item count > 0)
 show subitems
else
 show shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution was to use the [`MenuItem.SubmenuOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.submenuopened) event instead of the click event.